# Write a list of lists in an excel file

Tags: r, excel, list

We can easily make lists of lists

```
list1 <- list(a = 2, b = 3)
list2 <- list(c = "a", d = "b")
mylist <- list(list1, list2)
```

`mylist` is now a list that contains two lists.  To access `list1`, e.g., we can use `mylist[[1]]`.

My question is: how could I write `mylist` on a `excel` file, whose sheet are `list1` and `list2`?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want the file to look like?

Comment: Way too long to post as answer but I wrote a blog post about nested lists and writing to excel worksheets... https://ibecav.github.io/Functionalize/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to write a new Excel file and include the names of the list elements, you can do the following:

```r
list1 <- list(a = 2, b = 3)
list2 <- list(c = "a", d = "b")
mylist <- list(list1, list2)

names(mylist) <- c("list1", "list2")
library(openxlsx)
write.xlsx(setNames(as.list(lapply(mylist, data.frame)), names(mylist)), file="mylist.xlsx")
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>